# Show method definition/description in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, methods, definition

Is there a way to add a description to my methods in Xcode iOS project so I can see quick details when clicking on a desired method with OPTION + click like it can be done on Apple's API's methods (case bellow)?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 answers already on the subject. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174315/how-do-you-document-your-source-code-in-xcode) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958413/xcode-show-documentation-for-my-custom-classes).

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go with Appledoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right than all of this tools are for generating documentation and not for adding method's description. Am I right?