# Comments style for xCode

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

How shall I write (what style) the comments for public methods and properties in my classes so they would be visible in Quick Help window the same way they are for built in methods?

The absence of strong typed array in iOS creates bunch of issues for me, especially when a method accepts a NSArray*, if I wrote it 6 months ago, then I need for sure to go in that method and check what are actual types that must be stored in that array.

Thx

Comment: I think a similar question has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958413/xcode-show-documentation-for-my-custom-classes

Comment: if I understand correctly I have to run that tool each time I create a new method and write its description? Is kinda a little of overhead in here. There should be easier way, like I'm used to have in Visual Studio under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will have to regenerate the documentation whenever you want a change. Xcode does not pick up documentation on the fly based on your comments like Visual Studio can. This is confirmed by a comment in the question I linked to:

> Xcode's Quick Help uses your installed documentation sets to display its contents. Unless you create and install a documentation set for your classes, all Quick Help displays is a link to the header file where you declared the class, method, or data member.

Appledoc seems to be your best option. I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but it doesn't seem too bad.