# Using @link with Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, headerdoc

I'm using HeaderDoc to document my code and I would like to link to other methods in the documentation. I'm not trying to generate HTML (at least for now) but I do want it to appear in Xcode's right panel. The following is the documentation for `-applicationDidEnterBackground:` as it appears in Xcode. I want to achieve those blue links referencing other methods I wrote myself:

[image]

The docs say to use `@link`, but it doesn't seem to work:

Here's what I tried:

```
/**
 *  @abstract   Returns an array with a copy of all elements in the heap in sorted order.
 *
 *  @discussion The original heap remains unchanged. This getter uses Heap Sort which takes O(n log n),
 *              although it copies the heap first (in linear time). If losing the elements on the heap is
 *              acceptable you should use @link -removeAllObjectsWithArray: @/link instead, which is faster.
 */
```

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see it's not rendering properly. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958413/xcode-show-documentation-for-my-custom-classes) that `@link` is broken, but the comment dates back to 2013. Is there a fix? Am I doing it wrong?

Edit: I tried Santa's suggestion, this is the result:

```
/**
 *  @abstract   Whether the heap is empty.
 *
 *  @discussion An empty heap contains no objects, in which case this property returns <code>YES</code>.
 *              Returns <code>NO</code> otherwise, which also implies that calls to {@link count}
 *              return zero.
 */
```

Renders as:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to remove the `-` before the method signature in the documentation

Comment: Also, if you Command-click on any method (an Apple method or your own) it will take you to the header where you can see how they write their documentation.

Comment: @SantaClaus doesn't work. And it makes sense to use the `-` because it's part of the method's signature (I could have a class method with the same name)

Comment: I can't find any HeaderDocs from Apple. They don't seem to be using it. If you Cmd+Click a method you'll see that the docs are not there

Comment: I'm just looking at the way Apple does their docs, and they don't include the `-`. You might try using the `{@link ...}` syntax instead.

Comment: Where did you find that? Please see my edit!

Comment: I just command-clicked on some apple method and looked at the header file...that's how they do it so idk why it's not working

Comment: Which method? I couldn't find HeaderDocs yet

Comment: It was a Core Bluetooth header, but it doesn't matter since every header has docs

Comment: You are right, CoreBluetooth headers to seem to use HeaderDocs. I tried their notation, it's not working. I must be missing something

Comment: I don't think that the HeaderDocs we find there are the ones that actually get put into practice. Notice that in some situations the text is different! (ie., `CBCentralManager`'s `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:`)

Comment: Oh, we are probably missing something big here

Comment: It seems that using anchors helps! I'm not sure how yet